# change view inside Tab bar in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, tabbar

[image: this picture]
I have a custom tab bar in center of my screen and I have a tab bar view,
I have some button in one my tab bar view,
I want to change or replace my view to a new view(not tabs) inside current tab bar view

Comment: Please provide some code of what you've done already, and an example that explains what you want for us to be able to help you

Comment: can you post some code

Comment: why not include that `Tab Bar` as an item of tabBar